# How to create pre-signed S3 object URL and access it via VPC endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, vpc-endpoint

I have a service that generates a pre-signed URL for S3 objects accessible via the internet.

I am trying to figure out how to generate a similar pre-signed URL while using a VPC endpoint to the bucket/object to limit the traffic to only that endpoint's local network.

How can this be done?

I can access from CLI, but cannot get the pre-signed URL for an object to work (over the VPC endpoint)...

aws s3 --region us-west-2 --endpoint-url https://bucket.vpce-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx.s3.us-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com ls s3://bucket_name/

above works, so the vpc endpoint is functioning.  How do I need to create the pre-signed URL to utilize it and not the public internet networking?

So, let's say the pre-signed URL is:
https://tl-vpc-endpoint-test.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test1.zip?.....

What does it need to be to utilize the VPC endpoint?

Comment: Same as regular S3-presigned url. Sadly your question is not clear. What exactly did you try? Why it didn't work? Any errors?

Comment: is the url based on the endpoint or the original https://s3.region.amazonaws.com/... 

How is the routing enforced to the endpoint?

Comment: The endpoint automatically catches the s3 url. Please try and see how it goes. If you have issues, please make new question with your endpoint and test details.

Comment: keep getting: <Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

i dont understand how the routing is supposed to work to the LAN IP when <bucket-name>.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com resolves to a public IP...

Comment: Assume I need to replace the hostname in the pre-signed URL with the endpoint, no?

Comment: added some additional details above to avoid the line wrapping. thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can generate your vpc endpoint presigned url like this:

aws s3 --endpoint-url https://bucket.vpce-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx.s3.us-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com presign s3://awsexamplebucket/test2.txt

Then you will get something like this:

https://bucket.vpce-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx.s3.us-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com/awsexamplebucket/test2.txt?.......